# How can you process a file uploaded with Python-Flask?

Tags: python, file-upload, flask

I've created a basic upload function using flask, based on the tutorial in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxFaa_FNdL4&t=793s) video.

The code in the 'main' python file can be found below. Essentially, when run the 'webpage' has an upload function and once you select file(s), these are added to a folder which is either created or exists already alongside the other folders in the flask programme.

My question is this: I want to upload files to be immediately processed by another block of non-flask python code- what principles should be followed to do this? For example- to process a CSV file with a python script? Can the python script theoretically just be residing in a HTML file in the templates folder which gets activated when a suitable file is uploaded?

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


app = Flask(__name__)

APP__ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("upload.html")

@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP__ROOT, 'data/')
    print(target)

    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    for file in request.files.getlist("file"):
        print(file)
        filename = file.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)

    return render_template("complete.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4555, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a function to process your file. In your view function, call that new function.

For example:

```
def process_file(filename):
    print filename

...
file.save(destination)
process_file(destination)
```

If your processing is too long, maybe you want to process it in background, after the request is done. Python has tools to help you do that, like `python-rq` or `celery`.